# how can I divide the frequency of bigram pair by unigram word?

Tags: python

below is my code.

```
from __future__ import division
import nltk
import re

f = open('C:/Python27/brown_A1_half.txt', 'rU')
w = open('C:/Python27/brown_A1_half_Out.txt', 'w')

#to read whole file using read()

filecontents = f.read()
from nltk.tokenize import sent_tokenize
sent_tokenize_list = sent_tokenize(filecontents)

for sentence in sent_tokenize_list:
    sentence = "Start " + sentence + " End"
    tokens = sentence.split()
    bigrams = (tuple(nltk.bigrams(tokens)))
    bigrams_frequency = nltk.FreqDist(bigrams)
    for k,v in bigrams_frequency.items():
        print k, v
```

then the printing result is "(bigrams), its frequency ". here, what I want is
for each bigram pair, divide the bigram frequency by the first appearing unigram word frequency. (for example, if there is a bigram ('red', 'apple') and its frequency is "3", then I want to divide it by the frequency of 'red').
This is for obtaining the MLE prob, that is "MLE prob = Counting of (w1, w2) / Counting of (w1)" . help me plz...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can add the following in the for loop (after print k, v):

```
number_unigrams = tokens.count(k[0])
prob = v / number_unigrams
```

That should give you the MLE prob for each bigram.

Comment: thanks so much. can I ask two more questions...?( I hope it's not violation of the rule in this sites..) (1)How can I sort the k, v value according to the highest frequency? I want the bigrams arrayed according to high frequency and MLE prob too.. (2) second, I want to sum up whole v value to make whlole counting of bigram...

Comment: (1) To sort the values by frequency, i don't know another solution but to copy all frequency values into a list and sort that. You can do `freq_list.append(v)` in your loop, and after that call `freq_list.sort()`.  (2) Go through that list and add the values to a sum variable (can also be done in the same loop). I don't know if it's against the rules, I am quite new here myself :D